# Can I list the parent_name of a child case in the child case module case list?

Tags: commcare

I have a module of child cases (type = alert) of a parent case and I would like to NOT have the user select the parent case first, but simply see a list of all the alert subcases. However, I do want to display the parent_name of the child case alert in this list. Is it possible to list the parent_name property as a property in the case list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use `parent/name` for this.